# Pool of very different PCs

Tags: gpu-mining

I would like to mine XMR on 20 PC's. They are very different in terms of power. I think to use some proxy. Could give me a piece of advice which proxy to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [xmrig-proxy](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig-proxy) or [xmr-node-proxy](https://github.com/Snipa22/xmr-node-proxy) should suffice.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote not well. The question is what to choose if workers are very different (2 times).

Comment: xmrig-proxy for sure allows you to set per worker diff target. With such a low (20) set of workers though, you could just as well have them connect directly to a pool.